# MYSQL QUERY FALSE although syntax is right

Tags: php, mysql

Im a beginner in PHP learning how to combine PHP with mysql. I successfully made my login page, now im making my register page. Im now in the process of checking to see if the query is TRUE before i continue to program but i keep getting "false" when i do var_dump on the query. Im checking to make sure username don't = an existing one, than i'll move on to do the same for email.

```
<?php

require 'main.inc.php';

if(!checkuser()){

if(isset($_POST['register'])){

//Returning the value the user put if any
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password_again = $_POST['password_again'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

//CHeck to see if the user left any blank spaces
if( !empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($password_again) && !empty($email)){

    if($password != $password_again){
        echo '<strong>Password did not match</strong>';
    }

    else{

        //Telling PHP what we want to get
        $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=$username";

        //Sending out the Query
        $query_run = mysql_query($query);
        var_dump($query_run);

    }
}

else{
    echo '<strong>Please Fill Out All Forms</strong>';
}
}

?>

<form action='register.php' method='POST'>

<p><input type='text' name='username' placeholder='username' /></p>
<p><input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' /></p>
<p><input type='password' name='password_again' placeholder='Confirm Password' /></p>
<p><input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email' /></p>
<p><input type='submit' name='register' value='Create Your Account' /></p>

</form>

<?php
}

else {
echo 'You are already registered';
}

?>
```

Comment: I love beginners staring off using deprecated PHP libraries (mysql_*). Anyway learn about SQL injection

Comment: 1) DO NOT USE `mysql_*` in PHP. 2) `where username = "$username"`

Comment: @EdHeal I want to understand the basic principles first, than move on to the latest.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp So how would i be able to fix this with mysqli or pop.

Comment: @DIKwame - Start by learning mysqli_ library - why learn old stuff?

Comment: @EdHeal Because MYSQLi builds of mysql, and theres no good tutorials on the latest one. If i understand mysql, i can grasp the concept of MYSQLi easily.

Comment: replace `$username` with `'$username'`

Comment: Here's a free downvote as a gift for using deprecated crap and learning obsolete stuff. And I'm note sure why you say there aren't any good tutorials on mysqli, the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is great.

Answer (score -1):

$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username';

use this instead...